# How can I install Eldy on Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, installation

I have a question for you. I found this software [Eldy](http://eldy.eu) and it says it works on Linux. However, I am unsure how to install it on Ubuntu. [This page](http://deb.vegans.it) (from the Eldy folks) appears to say how to install it, but I'm confused. It requires you to download a DEB file, but it explains some terminal commands needed. Also, [here](https://linuxforelderly.wordpress.com/2009/07/14/eldy-20-targz-for-download/) it says a newer version is available. How exactly should I install Eldy and where should I download it from?

I really appreciate all your help. Have a good day!

Comment: The text linuxforelderly.wordpress.com/2009/07/14/eldy-20-targz-for-download/ should read https://linuxforelderly.wordpress.com/2009/07/14/eldy-20-targz-for-download/ and you can copy and paste it (or just click the link above to view). I couldn't have more than 2 links in my post. Thank you!

Comment: get errors. What do I do? E: package 'sun-java6-jre' has no installation candidate E: unable to locate package eldy.

Answer (score 1):

To install Eldy, make sure that Java6 jre is installed, if not, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo apt-get install sun-java6-jre
```

Once done, `deb http://deb.vegans.it binary/` to your source list editing “/etc/apt/sources.list” and adding at the bottom.  To edit:

```
sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Save the file, and close it.  Then you need to run

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install eldy
```

Once finished enjoy eldy running:

```
sudo java -jar /usr/local/eldy/eldy.jar
```

<sup>Source:Eldy linux</sup>

Answer (score 0):

To install Eldy in Ubuntu, first you need to have Java 6 JRE installed. Just press next link an follow the instructions to install the package: [openjdk-6-jre](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/openjdk-6-jre) . More informations about installing Java 6 JRE can be found here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Java. The old method (`sudo apt-get install sun-java6-jre`) reported on http://deb.vegans.it/  is not supported anymore.

Now, you will ustall Eldy using the command line. Open a [terminal](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal#Starting_a_Terminal) using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> and type in next commands followed by <kbd>Enter</kbd>:

- `sudo -H gedit /etc/apt/sources.list` - this will open the file `/etc/apt/sources.list` with gedit in which you must add this line at the end: `deb http://deb.vegans.it binary/`. Save the file and close it.
- `sudo apt-get update` -  this will update Ubuntu with new sources.
- `sudo apt-get install eldy` - this will install Eldy in your Ubuntu.
- `java -jar /usr/local/eldy/eldy.jar` - this will run Eldy (use this command every time when you want to run Eldy).

Source: http://deb.vegans.it/.